# Emulator: emulator: WARNING: UpdateCheck: Failure: Error on android studio

Tags: performance, emulation

I am facing the "Emulator: emulator: WARNING: UpdateCheck: Failure: Error" when run the emulator after updating my android studio 3.0.1 but it was working fine with previous version.Also I observed that it is working now with low API level(kitakt:19).

Answer (score 0):

For the future record, I had a similar issue right after I updated the SDK constraints. I just deleted all of my emulators and created a new one.